# HTML5 Video not getting hidden in media query

Tags: css, html, video

Similar problem was posted but the answers there did not help me.

I have a responsive web site in which the whole background is a mp4 format video. On desktop browsers there is no problem. The code for that is below

```
     @media screen and (min-width: 400px)
 {

    video {
    position: fixed; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
    width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -100;
    background-size: cover;
    }

 }
```

And the media query for small screens is below

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 400px) {
background: url(../images/tanisalimmobilebackground.jpg);
    background-size:cover;

    video {
        display:none!important;
    }

}
```

The problem is when I view it on iOS Chrome and Safari the video is not hidden and is on the  background with controls shown and not started.

What i want to do is if the width is at a max of 400 px , I want to show the jpg that is mentioned above.

Comment: Have you checked the width of your device? maybe it's over 400px?

Comment: Did you use the [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify the element that should have the background. E.g:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 400px) {
    someelement{
        background: url(../images/tanisalimmobilebackground.jpg);
        background-size:cover;
    }
    video {
        display:none!important;
    }

}
```